# Why is S3 deleting the data after 1 day when I set retention_period: 90d?

Tags: grafana-loki

Here is the config I used to start Loki with helm:

```
loki:
  enabled: true

  compactor:
    retention_enabled: true
  limits_config:
    retention_period: 90d

  auth_enabled: false
```

I omitted some parts, I am using S3. What I see is that the log entries are kept in Loki in S3 for one day, instead of 90! Why is that?

S3 is not AWS hosted but provided by the company I work for.

I am fairly sure that there's no object expiry policy set on the database, because the service owner claims no objects would be removed automatically, and this command:

```
aws --no-verify-ssl  --endpoint-url https://my-server.company.com s3api get-bucket-lifecycle-configuration --bucket my-bucket
```

replies with NoSuchLifecycleConfiguration